# Как хранить собственные типы данных внутри QListWiget

Tags: c++, qt

Я пытаюсь сохранить собственный класс (по сути просто контейнер с разными полями, датой временем, и другими типами) внутри QListWiget, для последующего использования. Однако в этот QListWigdet допускается лишь сохранение QListWidgetItem.

Я попробовал достаточно странное костыльное решение, и сделал родителем моего класса QListWidgetItem, к тому же перегрузив операции сравнения (так как эти айтемы должны быть внутри отсортированы по особому признаку), и что самое интересное - такой подход работает, записи успешно добавляются, и как положено сортируются.

Но проблема начинается тогда, когда я пытаюсь вытащить эти записи из QListWidget, потому что он возвращает свой QListWidgetItem а не MyItem. Судя по всему, моё решение оказалось неэффективным, потому прошу подсказки, каким образом в QListWidget сохранять и вытаскивать собственные классы, заранее благодарю

Comment: Вообще-то ```QListWidget``` не предназначен для хранения чего бы то ни было. Его задача - отображение данных в виде списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить и свой `MyItem`. Для этого надо указать тип итема например при помощи вот [этого конструктора](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidgetitem.html#QListWidgetItem):

```
сlass MyItem : public QListWidgetItem {
public:
    static int type; 
    MyItem(..., QListWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QListWidgetItem(parent, MyItem::type) {
    }
}
```

cpp:

```
int MyItem::type = QListWidgetItem::UserType + 1;
```

Теперь, при получении элемента списка из `QListWidget` надо просто проверить его тип и, в случае необходимости, сделать соответствующие приведения:

```
QListWidgetItem* item = listWidget->item(<row>);
if (item->type() == MyItem::type) {
    MyItem* myitem = static_cast<MyItem*>(item);
    //... 
}
```

Кроме того, можно наследовать `QListWidget`, добавить в наследник метод, например, `MyListWidget::myItem(int row)`, в котором и производить данные манипуляции.

Кроме того, в самом QListWidgetItem есть метод [setData(int role, const QVariant& value)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidgetitem.html#setData) при помощи которого вы можете хранить значения множества типов данных, включая пользовательские

Comment: Решение показалось крайне занятным, вроде что то вычитал про QVariant (он оказался не очень понятен), решил попробовать через первый блок кода, однако он ругается на отсутствие подходящего конструктора. Может я что-то недоглядел?

Comment: @voodookiidoo не знаю, вот этот конструктор https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#QListWidgetItem

Comment: @voodookiidoo а, там нужен parent типа `QListWidget` у меня был указан QWidget - исправил

Comment: QVariant  только на первый взгляд сложен - на самом деле все не так и он очень удобен для хранения различных данных, поэтому (для уменьшения случаев наследования) его и добавили в `QListWidgetItem`

Answer (score 2):

Такие задачи решаются немного по другому.

Все данные должны хранится где то у Вас в массиве структур/классов (а может в файле, с отдельным индексом или базе). Дальше, нужно написать специальный класс - модель. Основная его задача - отвечать на два вопроса - сколько элементов в списке должно быть и дать данные по нужному элементу (по его индексу). И все. Теперь список сможет запрашивать только то, что ему нужно. Просто представьте себе, что у Вас список на 100к элементов (толковый словарь) и хочется все слова показывать с коротким объяснением. Все загрузить в список может быть очень долго, более того, пользователь никогда может и не увидеть половину загруженных элементов.

Как это сделать? Прочитать документацию https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.13/model-view-programming.html

Потом присмотреться к https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.13/model-view-programming.html#a-read-only-example-model - пример модели с доступом только на чтение

Вот пример с той статьи с моими комментариями

```
class StringListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    StringListModel(const QStringList &strings, QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QAbstractListModel(parent), stringList(strings) {}

    // эта функция возвращает кол-во строк, которые должны быть отображены.
    // как минимум, она помогает настроить правильно скрол
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    // эта функция возвращает элемент по его индексу.
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
    // а это уже "улучшения" - названия столбцов
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                        int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

private:
    // а это авторы статьи используют для хранения данных
    // Вы можете использовать что то свое - тут Вы вольны.
    QStringList stringList;
};
```

role - это то, что именно хочет список от Вас. Детально - https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.13/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum - например, он может попросить тултип для элемента или сказать, что элемент сейчас редактируют и нужно выдать что то особое (например, это табличный редактор формул. В обычном режиме - формулы картинкой, в режиме редактирования - строкой в техе).

Посмотрим на реализации. Вот тут вообще все просто

```
int StringListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return stringList.count();
}
```

тут чуточку сложнее, но очевидно

```
QVariant StringListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    // если запросили неверный индекс - просто возвратим "пустоту"
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (index.row() >= stringList.size())
        return QVariant();
    // нас интересует только отображение
    // это ключевая строка, которая возвращает строку для отображения
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return stringList.at(index.row());
    else
        return QVariant();
}
```

Ну и последняя функция. Я думаю, что тут нечего комментировать.

```
QVariant StringListModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                     int role) const
{
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
        return QStringLiteral("Column %1").arg(section);
    else
        return QStringLiteral("Row %1").arg(section);
}
```

И остался последний штрих - подцепить модель

```
auto* model = new StringListModel();
QListView *list = new QListView(splitter);
list->setModel(model);
```

ну и не забыть эту модель наполнить данными, но это уже не ко мне.

Также следует заметить, что список может запрашивать элементы в произвольном порядке, не нужно закладываться на то, что он будет их запрашивать один за другим.

Я использовал этот подход, он очень хорошо работает, данные хранятся в одном месте и все красиво отображается. Основные тормоза - наполнение этого списка, но это уже не к Qt.